# Updater XML script on server targetplatform for joomla 4.3/4.4/5.0

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-5.x

In my XML script of my extension for the Joomla! updater, i need to allow the updates when the extension is installed on : Joomla! 4.3.x, 4.4.x and 5.0.x.
I have set in my XML file the targetplatform like that but it allow the update only on Joomla! 5.0. I have added recently the support for Joomla! 5.0

```
<targetplatform name="joomla" version="4.(3|4)|5.0"/>
```

What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: After i have made others checks on Joomla! 4.3.4 and Joomla! 5.0, it works like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After to have re-checked it works by doing that :

```
<targetplatform name="joomla" version="4.(3|4)|5.0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
^(4\.([3-9]|10)|5\.([0-9]|10))\b
```

Feel free to change the range of supported versions.

Answer (score 0):

i‘ve simply changed to .* for compatible extensions. its not the best way but the best i could find so far…